# SilverStripe displaying redundant tabs

Tags: silverstripe

Whenever I set up a `$has_many` or `$many_many` relationship SilverStripe will create a corresponding tab in the top tab strip. I am creating a `GridField`, assigning it to a variable and injecting it into the main tab. This works fine but the 'Tiles' tab still remains even though it is empty.

```
$fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Main',
    [
        ... Other fields ...,
        $tiles
    ]
);
```

I have tried `$fields->removeByName('Tiles');` but that removes the tab and the field. Is there any way to remove the top tab and keep the field?

**Main Tab** (tiles gridfield down the bottom)

[image]

**Tiles Tabs** (empty)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `Tiles` tab before the new `Tiles` `GridField` is added in:

```
$fields->removeByName('Tiles');

$fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Main',
    [
        ... Other fields ...,
        $tiles
    ]
);
```

Comment: So simple... i feel like i tried everything but that! Thanks for the fix :)